# Getting virtual memory page size by java code

Tags: java

Is it possible to get virtual memory page size of the OS on which a java application is running as a java int variable? If yes, how?

Comment: There is no guarantee that you actually have virtual memory in your system, So I believe this is platform-and-os-dependent. What OS are you working on? Come to think about it, perhaps it is undefined - you can have several different sizes on one system.

Comment: I'm working on Ubuntu. In the accepted answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15923075/the-best-way-to-use-vbos it is mentioned that "if you want to use glMapBuffer making the buffer object a multiple of the host page size is very nice to the whole system". So that's why I want to get it. If java can't get it, then I'll just set it to 4kiB.

Comment: On x86/Linux, using 4KB sounds like a sure bet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible using undocumented APIs.  `sun.misc.Unsafe` has a method [pageSize()](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/misc/Unsafe.html#pageSize) which according to the documentation:

> Report the size in bytes of a native memory page (whatever that is).
>   This value will always be a power of two.

Sample code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import sun.misc.Unsafe;

public class PageInfo
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    throws Exception
    {
        Field f = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        Unsafe unsafe = (Unsafe)f.get(null);

        int pageSize = unsafe.pageSize();
        System.out.println("Page size: " + pageSize);
    }
}
```

Be aware that `sun.misc.Unsafe` is undocumented, unsupported and may change with later releases of JDK.  My suggestion, if you need to get page size info and want to use `Unsafe`, is to use it exists but fall-back to a sensible default (e.g. 4K) if needed (e.g. if the class or method no longer exists).

Answer (score -3):

See the following class; you can get an instance with getRuntime() -> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html

EDIT: As has been suggested in the comments, I should provide more details on where to go from there. You'd need to run a couple different scripts for different OS-es; you can get the type by using `System.getProperty()`.

You can find sample scripts by googling for "[os] + [memory page size] + script".

Note this would be a rather chippy solution, and I'm not saying it's nice, just that it's possible.

ALSO: Another idea I got when I googled this (though I'm not sure if this will work, as I've not done it) is to get the C code from the [Wikipedia page on pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_%28computer_memory%29) and import it as native java.

Comment: Runtime includes no method which returns the page size.

Comment: Au contraire, `Runtime.exec()`.

Comment: With which he should run what ?

Comment: @blgt why not giving more details?