# Do these library functions use the native system's functionality?

Tags: java

I just want to know these two libraries use system functionality?

```
Field f = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
f.setAccessible(true);
Unsafe un = (Unsafe) f.get(null);

int ps = un.pageSize();
System.out.println("Page size: " + ps);
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is not safe and not cross-platform-compatible.

- The way you are getting the `Unsafe` itself is public supported Java API from the package `java.lang.reflect`. This code will run on all platforms, with all implementations of JVMs, because it is part of Java's public API.
- The object `un` you are getting using the public supported API itself is not present on any JVMs other than the Oracle/Sun JVM, because it's private API to that JVM implementation. For example, your code will not run on the IBM JVM, since `sun.misc.Unsafe` will not be present there.

I think the Java 8 `javac` compiler by Oracle/Sun will even warn you when you compile your code (this compiler is not used if you build your project with Eclipse's built-in features), because you are using a private API.

---

Yes, your solution will return you the native memory page size, but it will possibly not run on all platforms.

Comment: ok ,according your explanation I got that this libraries use system function,am I right?so Is there any way to get page size without system functions like create array ?

Comment: What do you mean by "system function"? Yes, this will return you the native page size.

Comment: In my exercise for OS lesson ; I should  measure page size without use prepare function for it . and i don't have idea ! it was my point to say "system function"

Comment: Yes, your code will use the system functions. It returns what is happening in the core, in the native part, however you want to call it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19093391/4464702 Look here for a detailed report on what `sun.misc.Unsafe.pageSize()` does. **You are doing it correctly in your code, as long as you don't care about portability. For your programming lessons this is the correct solution.**

Comment: If you care a little bit about my effort, consider clicking the checkmark and the upvote button next to my answer.